# Show open/download file option in mozilla

Tags: c#

I need to download a file from the server. The code for it is as shown below :

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string fileName = context.Request.QueryString["fileName"];

    string filePath = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "/TempFolder/" + fileName;

    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            int _READ_LEN = 3000;

            int bLength = _READ_LEN;
            BinaryReader bReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);

            if (bReader.BaseStream.Length < _READ_LEN)
                bLength = (int)bReader.BaseStream.Length;

            while (bReader.BaseStream.Position != bReader.BaseStream.Length)
            {
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(bReader.ReadBytes(bLength));

                if ((bReader.BaseStream.Length - bReader.BaseStream.Position) < _READ_LEN)
                    bLength = (int)(bReader.BaseStream.Length - bReader.BaseStream.Position);
            }
        }

        context.Response.Flush();

        File.Delete(filePath);
    }
}
```

When I try to download file in Mozilla, it automatically downloads the file without asking to either open/download the file whereas it shows this option while working in IE.
I need this option to be shown in Mozilla too. 
I tried to search the stuff but could not find anything useful.
Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If Mozilla Firefox automatically downloads a file without asking for a destination, it is very likely configured to work that way. Check out [Mozilla Firefox Help](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik this is browser-dependent behavior (browser settings include ways to deal with different file types).

If you wish to have a browser-independent way to deal with this, I suggest using e.g. a modal popup box that prompts the user with a choice. Depending on the answer, you can construct a query string that can be dealt with inside your file handler.